# How to recover user data missing after reset of computer

Tags: 12.04, restore, reset, rm

I was trying to figure out how watch `4oD` (as like many people it just loads forever and never actually plays anything) so I used the help on this page: [4oD (UK) - Can't stream](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199113/4od-uk-cant-stream)

I started with this:

> Close all browser windows and then:
>
> Remove the adobe cache:
>
> ```
> rm ~/.adobe -rf
> ```

But terminal said it couldn't remove this as it was busy. Everything was closed so I thought if I reset my computer it would stop this program being in use and allow me to continue the process. However when I logged on again EVERYTHING was gone! Music, Documents, Downloads etc. (I am definitely signed into the correct user).

Is there anyway I can reset my computer to an hour ago or something to reverse this? I honestly don't understand how I did this!

Comment: Did you type a literal `*` character in running that `rm` command?

Comment: And how did you reboot? Did you just switch it off or used *Magic SysRq*? (The REISUB stuff)

Comment: Sorry I thought I was going to get an email when somebody replied!                         No I didn't type a * character just the code that I typed above and I restarted (sorry not reset) by going to 'shut down...' (top right icon on screen) > 'restart'. Thanks for replying!