# How to get 4od channel4 working [2015, UK]

Tags: streaming

http://www.channel4.com/programmes/ used to work with the [previous hacks](https://askubuntu.com/a/239504/28930) installing an ported version of "hal" but it appears to have stopped working (Nov 2015).

I've tried Firefox, Chromium and Chrome, on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've installed hal from http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/ and I've ensured the daemon was running (required *sudo*) before starting the browser.

**Firefox** just shows a blank grey space where the player goes; **Chrome** shows the play buttons but then it just hangs on the endless ubiquitous rotating frustration indicator; **Chromium** says "flash upgrade required" (I have installed today flashplugin-installed giving me Shockwave Flash v. 11.2 r202)

Obviously the answer would be for public broadcaster Channel 4 to produce a service that was accessible to a wide range of users, but as they've always seemed a little miffed that the internet was invented I don't hold out any hope here so wondering if anyone had found a recent workaround?

Comment: probably should use a bounty to get a new answer rather than a new question... but we can merge stuff later.  One of the answers on the original question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/199113/4od-uk-cant-stream?lq=1) says to use the youtube channel.  Does this cover what you are after?

Comment: Nah, they removed their youtube content "to focus on channel4.com"... ahem. Unfamiliar with how to use a bounty. Did wonder what the etiquette was for "same question, different context because things have moved on since 2013" type things. Happy to be advised :-)

Comment: I've created a working answer on the original question ... dont shoot me down!  If you want a different answer then click the "start a bounty" link and choose one of the reasons for the bounty and add a message as to what type of answer you are looking for.